# Excel crosstab to tabular format

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to make a weekly time tracker that then takes the time from calendar looking format and converts into a tabular format on the fly.  The end goal is to have the tabular data in a format that can be copied and pasted into a sheet so I can run other functions on it.  I cant use VBA or custom functions so it has to be stock formula based.

I can get the dates to repeat as needed but cant figure out how to get the job numbers to populate to match the dates.  Summing up the hours per date and job number will be a breeze.

I have linked a sample file sheet with the weekly calendar format needed and the desired outcome based on the sample data.

I think it might be a simple solution but I have looked too closely at it to recognize what needs to be done.

[Sample file](https://ludvik365-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/cneu_ludvik_com/EV9uz7UZGbpGjWxSyYGYZgABsI6LhHjcuUrHyQzXYPYSfw?e=o2vWXE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the job numbers, you can try this formula (using the range references from your sample worksheet:

```
N5: =AGGREGATE(15,6,1/(1/((INDEX($B$7:$I$16,0,MATCH(L5,$B$6:$I$6,0))>0)*ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROWS($B$7:$B$16))))),COUNTIF($L$5:L5,L5))
```

It is relatively simple since your job numbers are sequential and match the position in the array.  Although, if the job numbers were random, or alphanumeric, it would just be a matter of embedding the above formula in another `INDEX` function.

```
=INDEX($B$7:$B$16,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/(1/((INDEX($B$7:$I$16,0,MATCH(L5,$B$6:$I$6,0))>0)*ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROWS($B$7:$B$16))))),COUNTIF($L$5:L5,L5)))
```

Look through it and ask questions about the parts you don't understand.  The formula evaluation tool will be useful.

Comment: That was a flawless victory!  Thank you!  I used the formula for the job numbers in random sequence.  I have yet to dig through the formula but wanted to quickly thank you for the solution.